# ASP.NET 5 tag returning 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: tag-helpers, asp.net5

I am newbie with asp.net 5 and I wonder if someone could give me some guidance.

I have a project where I am rendering an Angular 2 app with asp.net 5 using the Steve Sanderson [template](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/05/02/angular2-react-knockout-apps-on-aspnet-core/) (first version with 1.0.0-rc1-final).

It works ok on IIS Express but when I publish to Azure it doesn't.

I tried changing some settings but decided to publish on IIS locally to see, if could reproduce the error (500) but in an environment where I am more confortable.

And yes after publishing I have the same error but I still don't know how to get a more detailed one.
I have tried with:

- `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();`
- web.config
- web.config `stdoutLogEnabled="true"`
- web.config `<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />`
- etc

but none of them worked.

If I remove the tag in charge of rendering the app 
   `<app asp-prerender-module="ClientApp/boot-server" asp-prerender-webpack-config="webpack.config.js">Loading...</app>` it works.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I was a little be confused because I changed the template to RC2 and then back to RC1 and everything was kind of mess (about all in my mind).

I have studied a little be more of asp.net 5 and how to use DNVM, DNU and DNXs which I should have done before and now reviewing what is happening from the command line I have more clues of what to do.

Basically I had a problem with the dnx version first, then with one of the node dependency and now I am struggling with something to do with my webpack config which I have to review more deeply as well.

Thanks.